# How to update a widget after async reciever done?

Tags: flutter

How to update text widget after async reciever done?

```
  //it is a stateless widget
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String appName = '';

    PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((PackageInfo packageInfo) {
      appName = packageInfo.appName;
      print('$appName');
    });

    return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('$appName'), //how to update this widget?
```

Comment: calling setstate over a statefulwidget i guess

Comment: you widget must be Stateful and then use setState to change  the value

Comment: There is a better solution for a simple Future, you can use a FutureBuilder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `FutureBuilder` [Widget of the week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo)

just wrap your `Text` and check the snapshot value

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
       child: FutureBuilder<PackageInfo>(
         future: PackageInfo.fromPlatform(),
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
           return Text(snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.appName : "");
         }
       ),
      ),

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use stateful widget and set the state like this

```
PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((PackageInfo packageInfo) {
  setState(() {
    appName = packageInfo.appName;
  });
  print('$appName');
});
```

Comment: For a simple Future and a text is advisable to use a FutureBuilder instead of changing to a StatefulWidget